# Limit child window based on record id

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a grid view with multiple records. There is two type of records: recordTypeA, and recordTypeB. For recordTypeA I want to limit the child windows I can open.  I can't have two copies (duplicate) of recordTypeA opened at the same time.

For example, if recordTypeA with a query string id of 1 is opened, I don't want to have another window with recordTypeA id 1 open, but I can have two recordTypeA open if they have different query string ids.

```
var g_windowReference = null;


function openwindow(windowUrl, isnotRecordB)
{

    var windowFeatures = "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,status=yes";

    if (typeof isnotRecordB == 'undefined') 
    {

        g_windowReference = window.open(windowUrl, windowFeatures);
        g_windowReference.focus();
    } 
    else 
    {
        window.open(windowUrl, windowFeatures);
        window.focus();

    }


    return false;
}

function closeWindow(windowUrl)
{
    if ( (g_windowReference !== null) && (g_windowReference.closed === false))
    {

            g_windowReference.close();
            g_windowReference = null;



    }

}
```

This code works fine unless I open recordTypeA with id 1 and then recordTypeA with id 2.  The record with id 2 overwrites the first one making me available of opening the record with 1 twice in different windows.

How can achieve the desired behavior?

Please help,

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the recordIds which have been opened of either type.

Look at the following simple implementation for this.

```
function WindowManager(recordType) {
    if(!recordType) {
        throw "Please provide a recordType";
    }

    var windows = {}; //recordId:window pairs {"typeA":window1, "typeB":window2}

    this.openWindow = function (windowUrl, recordId) {
        if(!recordId) {
            throw "Please provide recordId";
        }

        if( !windows[recordId] ) {//If recordId window is not found
            var newWindow = openwindow(windowUrl);
            windows[recordId] = newWindow; //Storing reference to close in future

            console.log("opened " + recordType + ":" + recordId);
        } else {
            throw "Window for recordId " + recordId + " of type " + recordType + " is already open";
        }
    }

    this.closeWindow = function (recordId) {
        if(!recordId) {
            throw "Please provide recordId";
        }

        var recordWindow = windows[recordId];
        recordWindow.close();

        delete windows[recordId];//removing window after it's closed

        console.log("closed " + recordType + ":" + recordId);

        return recordWindow;
    }

    this.getRecordType = function () {
        return recordType;
    }

    this.getOpenRecordIds = function () {
        return Object.keys(windows);
    }

    function openwindow (windowUrl, recordId) {
        var windowFeatures = "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,status=yes";

        var newWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowFeatures);
        newWindow.focus();

        return newWindow;
    }
}
```

**In Action**

[image]

**Note:** Create manager objects of each type and then use them to open or close windows as needed.